# Archive Template in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I want to create an archive page template for Wordpress that will look like this:

August 2009

- Post 4
- Post 3
- Post 2
- Post 1

July 2009

- Post 2
- Post 1

So, basically, I want all the posts from the blog, ordered descending by date and grouped by month.
Can someone provide me the PHP code for this?

Thanks!

PS: Wordpress version is 2.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function I created a while back.  It basically does what you want to do, but it's not a template.  Maybe you can adapt it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays a condensed list of the posts grouped by month/year. 
 *
 * @param $order The order of the posts.  Either 'DESC' or 'ASC', case sensitive.
 * @param $date_prefix Whether to prefix the posts with the month/date.
 * @param $display Whether to display the results or return it as a String. 
 */

function condensed_post_list($order='DESC', $date_prefix=true, $display=true){
    global $wpdb;

    if( !in_array($order, array('DESC','ASC' ) ) ) $order = 'DESC';
    $query = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_date FROM $wpdb->posts ".
             "WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status = 'publish' ".
             "ORDER BY post_date $order";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    ob_start();
    $current_month = '';
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        if( $current_month != mysql2date('F Y', $result->post_date)) {
            if( $current_month ) echo '</ul>';

            $current_month = mysql2date('F Y', $result->post_date );
            echo '<h2>'.$current_month.'</h2>';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        echo '<li>';
        echo ($date_prefix ? mysql2date('M j: ', $result->post_date) : '');
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($result->ID).'">';
        echo $result->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }
    if( $current_month ) echo '</ul>';

    if( $display ) {
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you,

Your snippet helped me a lot and I managed to create the archive page. The only difference is that instead of querying the database directly I am using Wordpress' get_posts function.

Here is the result: http://victorhurdugaci.com/archive/

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help - though instead of your SQL query I used some native wordpress functions - as I needed to only pull posts from a single category. I replaced your SQL with -  $results = query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&cat=3'); Great help though! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I used the above function, but replaced the SQL query with:

```
$results = query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&cat=3');
```

This allowed me to use the excellent function  @scompt.com wrote, but limit it to a single blog category.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot of the help. This is what I used with the code above.

```
function condensed_post_list($order='DESC', $date_prefix=true, $display=true)
{
    if( !in_array($order, array('DESC','ASC' ) ) ) $order = 'DESC';
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_status'     => 'publish');
    $results = get_posts($args);

    ob_start();
    $current_month = '';
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        if( $current_month != mysql2date('F Y', $result->post_date)) {
            if( $current_month ) echo '</ul>';

            $current_month = mysql2date('F Y', $result->post_date );
            echo '<h2>'.$current_month.'</h2>';
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        echo '<li>';
        echo ($date_prefix ? mysql2date('M j: ', $result->post_date) : '');
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($result->ID).'">';
        echo $result->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }
    if( $current_month ) echo '</ul>';
    if( $display ) {
        ob_end_flush();
    } 
    else {
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from @scompt.com's answer?